# Rails 3.2 - Production server is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have created a new server to host a rails 3.2 app with a mysql server hosted on the same server.

I keep getting 'xxxxx-xxxxx.linode.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (Mysql2::Error)

I have checked over all the config and it seems correct. I can access the mysql server using the mysql command, sequal pro and also was able to do a rake db:migrate like this:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_EV=production
```

I am using passenger and this is my database.yml

```
 production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: nst_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  timeout: 5000
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: We sort of have the same setup so maybe I can help. Make sure when you logged into mysql for the first time that you've create another user account which has permissions to write and create , update, and delete databases and tables. If you have that then make sure you have install the mysql2 gem for rails. Also you're run this command `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`.After you have done so restart your server and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried all of your points with no luck. Its the first time ive used this host so ill tried my normal host and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better try to connect via socket.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: nst_production
  pool: 5
  socket:  /tmp/mysql.sock 
  username: root
  password: password
  timeout: 5000
```